# Redirecting to a subdomain without changing the url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following url www.abc.xyz.com which redirects to www.xyz.com/abc and I am trying to create an htaccess file that will keep the url as www.abc.xyz.com but I am unable to do so with the following file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.xyz.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /abc/$1 [L]
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Are `DocumentRoot` of both domains same?

Comment: yes, the abc folder is on the root directory.

Comment: It is already opening the contents of abc subdirectory but the url changes from www.abc.xyz.com to www.xyz.com/abc which is what i don't want to happen

Comment: No my question when you **remove above rule**. Without above rule in place does `www.abc.xyz.com` open content of `www.xyz.com/abc` OR `www.xyz.com`

Comment: It opens up the www.xyz.com url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!abc/).*)$ abc/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: That didn't work, I'm really confused I get a 500 error on adding this to the .htaccess file

Comment: Can you check Apache error.log and tell me what the error causing 500?

Comment: You have to make sure there is no other rule below this.

Comment: Here are the errors, I'm really confused as i have never fiddled with .htaccess before https://paste.ee/p/DMuvl

Comment: `File does not exist` doesn't cause 500, I need specific error that is written by 500 error. Also just place above rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` and test. I need your Apache version also

Comment: I placed the rule in DocumentRoot as mentioned and thats how i got the error, also my error log doesn't have any other errors mentioned. And thats the only log available in the cpanel, My cpanel also doesn't have any option to see the version of apache I am running. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67408/discussion-between-bazinga777-and-anubhava).